# Sending class object through Data class

Tags: android, android-workmanager, workmanagers

Android has recently introduced [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) for scheduling tasks. One of the powerful feature of this [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) is chaining multiple tasks through [combine](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation.html#combine), [then](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation.html#then) and [beginWith](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#beginWith) operators. [Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data) class is being used to send data between these tasks. But After going through the [Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data) and [Data.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data.Builder) class, I haven't found the way to send Class object through [Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data) class between different tasks, not even through [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable) or [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).
How can I send class object between different tasks?

Comment: potentially an XY problem. why would you want to send a class?

Answer (score 2):

The `Data` is a lightweight container which is a simple key-value map and can only hold values of primitive & Strings along with their String version. It is really meant for light, intermediate transfer of data. It shouldn't be use for and is not capable of holding Serializable or Parcelable objects.

Do note, the size of data is limited to 10KB when serialized.

Comment: where have you found the limitation of 10KB? Can you provide a link to the source / documentation?

Comment: @hardysim you can refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data . Read second paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798329/workmanager-data-builder-does-not-support-parcelable)

@Sagar does point out the correct answer to your question, just posting my answer here for people looking for potential work arounds.